# How to display the values on the bar plot for each bar with barh() in this case?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, bar-chart

[image]

how to add the values of the bar on the top of it in this case?

What I am trying to get:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add is as [**`matplotlib.axes.Axes.text`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html).
If you have a plot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
values = [150, 80, 10]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.barh(labels, values)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can add labels with this loop (you may need to adjust x axis limits in order to fit labels):

```
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    ax.text(value + 3, i, str(value))
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(xmin, 1.1*xmax)
```

[image]